# Ubuntu start up view changed due to gnome shell

Tags: unity, gnome, login, startup

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr on my laptop.

Its default Desktop Environment was Unity. I installed gnome-desktop-environment then I could use both unity DE and gnome DE on my laptop.

This made my bootup screen change to the Ubuntu GNOME logo, instead of the vanilla Ubuntu logo.

That's OK, but after some time I thought I will only use Unity, so I removed gnome-shell package and all of its configurations.

Now gnome-shell is removed but still I can see Ubuntu GNOME logo during boot. I can't see the cool Ubuntu logo which I saw at previous when Ubuntu 14.04 was freshly installed.

Is there any way to get back that look on starting up the system?

previous screen image:

[image: previous screen image]

I want it back.

my login screen is OK, login screen image:

[image: login screen image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to remove the plymouth themes. Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text
```

Comment: Yep it Helped :) Thanks! :) 
I got another thing to change the plymouth theme [code]sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth . Another Thing I want to know how can I clean system cache/application cache thumbnail cache without using Ubuntu Tweak, cz my Ubuntu Tweak janitor is not working when I click clear

Comment: Sounds like a new question to me :-)